# Divide Minimum Spanning Tree into Equal (Disconnected) Chunks

Tags: clustering, algorithms, graph-theory

Does anybody know an efficient algorithm for dividing Minimum Spanning Tree (MST) into equal in size disconnected sub-trees? I'm not saying that it is a particularly hard task, but maybe there exist already a good solution to this problem.

EDIT: I've come up with an algorithm that may be good enough. I may post it here later. However, I would still appreciate some suggestions of other approaches to this problem. So far I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Its simply not always possible.

Consider the case where your minimum spanning tree is a star. You have n-1 leaf nodes, all connected to the central node. There is no way to split this into multiple subtrees that all have the same size except for size 1.

Comment: It is definitely a valid point. In such case I would take a step back and work on the vector representations (with e.g. FB's BigGraph).

Comment: This is not an exception, but the usual case. You almost-certainly hit this situation. Have you tried it?